# Unable to set variable from other contract, able to from outside

Tags: solidity, truffle, testrpc

I've got two contracts, A and B, I set them up in a truffle test separately.

```
A.new()...
B.new()...
```

A has a function bar, which sets a public boolean boo to true that is never read anywhere. B has a function, foo, that calls bar on a previously instantiated A.

```
contract A(){
    bool public boo = false;
    function bar() public {
        boo = true;
    }
}
contract B(){
    A public myA;
    function setA(address addr){
       myA = A(addr);
    }
    function foo() public {
       myA.bar();
    }
}
```

Now in my truffle test, I call bar two ways, directly, and thru b.foo().

```
a.bar();
b.setA(a.address);
b.foo();
```

The first call to bar works fine. The second call thru foo throws out of gas no matter how much gas I give it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I should add that I can read A.boo from B, just not write.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the out of gas exception really was an out of gas exception this time...